# >>/var/log/kube-apiserver.log not work for kubernetes1.6

Tags: logging, kubernetes

Currently, under kubernetes1.5.3, kube-apiserver.log and kube-controller-manager.log is generated by adding '1>>/var/log/kube-apiserver.log 2>&1' in /etc/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.yaml file. 
  When I upgrade the kubernetes version to 1.6.3, it not work. There is no log file created under /var/log. How to get the kubernetes log file?
  Thanks, much.

Answer (score 6):

For kubernetes1.6+, try the following options

#### `kube-apiserver`

```
--audit-log-path=/var/log/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.log --logtostderr=false
```

and restart `kube-apiserver`, you can find all logs for `kube-apiserver` in file `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-apiserver.log`.

#### `kube-controller-manager`

```
--log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --logtostderr=false
```

then restart `kube-controller-manager`, you will find:

- `ERROR` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.ERROR`;
- `FATAL` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.FATAL`;
- `INFO` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.INFO`;
- `WARNING` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-controller-manager.WARNING`;

#### `kube-scheduler`

```
 --log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --logtostderr=false
```

then restart `kube-scheduler`, you will find:

- `ERROR` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.ERROR`;
- `FATAL` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.FATAL`;
- `INFO` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.INFO`;
- `WARNING` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-scheduler.WARNING`;

#### `kubelet`

```
--log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --logtostderr=false
```

then restart `kubelet`, you will find:

- `ERROR` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kubelet.ERROR`;
- `FATAL` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kubelet.FATAL`;
- `INFO` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kubelet.INFO`;
- `WARNING` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kubelet.WARNING`;

#### `kube-proxy`

```
--log-dir=/var/log/kubernetes --logtostderr=false
```

then restart `kube-proxy`, you will find:

- `ERROR` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-proxy.ERROR`;
- `FATAL` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-proxy.FATAL`;
- `INFO` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-proxy.INFO`;
- `WARNING` logs in `/var/log/kubernetes/kube-proxy.WARNING`;

Comment: Thank you. I tried ,  it work, but have to set --logtostderr=false also. And in this way, the 'kubectl logs' command only shows error level log, info log will not be collect and print.

Comment: I see, you start k8s services as foreground processes,  so you need to set `--logtostderr=false` . But `kubectl logs`  only `Print the logs for a container in a pod or specified resource.`, so if shows only error level log, you maybe need to set the log lever for your applications in containers.

Comment: I also set `--logtostderr=false` in my k8s cluster and  I forgot it ...

Comment: How to rotate and delete old log .ERROR, .INFO and .WARNING files that are generated when using the `--log-dir=dir --logtostderr=false` options?

Answer (score 1):

```
ps -ef | grep kube
tail -f /var/log/message
```

See the kube* processes's options are configed right ?
And check the /var/log/message to find are there some errors about k8s?